# mapcache timeout does not work

Tags: mapcache

I try to seed a wms service that is very very slow. Therefore the seeding fails with the message **"Operation timed out after 600000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received"**.

It seems not to be possible to set the time out time. I found the connection_timeout option in the wms-source of the mapcache.xml-file but it not work and changed the value from 600 to 1800:

```
<connection_timeout>600</connection_timeout>
```

to

```
<connection_timeout>1800</connection_timeout>
```

but the error message remains the same "... 600000 milliseconds ...". The change seems not to be adopted. Even after a restart of the apache webserver.

The command for the seeding

```
mapcache_seed  -c mapcache.xml -t osm_eu_3035 -e 542100,-369400,7530900,6619400 -z 0,10
```

The osm_eu_3035 service uses the local very slow wms service.

What did I wrong? Is there any other possibility to increase the time out time?

Answer (score 1):

It could also be an apache setting.
eg:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#timeout

Reducing the size and metatiling can also help